# Modifying stress markers in Cyrillic words

Tags: php

This is used to change a Cyrillic word with a stress marker into the same Cyrillic word but with the stress marker separately represented as a number. As I want to return two values I pass two parameters by reference. I assume there is at most only one stress marker per word.

What could I improve here?

```
function seperateStress($word,&$cleanWord,&$stressLetter){
    $stressLetter=-1;
    $cleanWord="";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($word);$i++){

        if($word[$i]=="&" ){
            //echo $i."</br>";
            $stressLetter=$i;

            $i=$i+5;
        }else{
            $cleanWord .=$word[$i]; 
            //echo $word[$i].":".$i."</br>";
        }
    }


    //return array($cleansedWord,$stressedLetter);
}

//Sample Test run
$stressWord= "велосипе́ды";
$noStressWord="";
$stressLetter=-1;

seperateStress($stressWord,$noStressWord,$stressLetter);
echo $noStressWord."::".$stressLetter."</br>";
```

Comment: It appears that I have found another solution to the problem. I stumbled across php's multibyte string functions and I am thus able to avoid using this implementation myself. Great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I would look at the PHP manual and make sure you aren't recreating a function that already exists, but I have no experience with non ASCII characters so i don't feel comfortable with the terminology to look this up. I would suggest that you make sure of this though. This sounds like something that might already exist somewhere. As to your function, there are a few things that jumped out at me.

First are those references. They are a powerful tool, but I would be careful using them. They are relatively difficult to spot and not everyone knows what they do. Sometimes its better just to use plain return statements, but that is something you will have to decide based on the scope of this project. If its something that isn't likely to be used by others, then this is fine, otherwise you might think about changing it.

When incrementing a variable by more than one, a more elegant way of doing so is by using the following syntax. By the way, where did the five come from? Unless cyrillic always has three digit entities, then you run the risk of missing some of the escape sequence. For example `nbsp` is a four digit entity. I would use `strpos()` or something similar to find the position of the semicolon instead.

```
$i += 5;
```

`$stressLetter` and `$cleanWord` definitions are redundant. You set them to the same values before the function was called. The only reason this would be necessary is if you revert back to using a return value instead of references, and then you should remove those parameters from the parameter list and from the procedural code before the function call.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The reason I increment by five is because the string is something like врфвра&#134;вфыврю. On locating the ampersand I have found the stress marker and know I can skip the next few characters to get to the в. The reason the variables appear again is because I wanted to make sure they are null to start with as they are passed in as referecnes. I am using references because I wanted to return two values. Nobody else will look at this code I do not think. It's just for a pet project that I am doing in my own time.

Comment: If you wan't to return two values then return an array as you have commented out.